# JavaScript events not firing on target website

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a google chrome extension project that interacts with a few different websites programmatically via JavaScript generated events. Namely keypress, keydown & mouseclick.

However some of the websites block programmatically generated events.

i.e. if I type this, the keys work on all keys except for keys the website uses.

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  console.log("e",e);
  console.log("e.keyCode",e.keyCode);
};
```

Since this data in on the client side shouldn't I be able to programmatically manipulate it?

I'm wondering if there's some reason my event might not be firing on the target website.

Comment: Maybe it's inside the iframe and your content script doesn't have all_frames true. Maybe the site have called e.stopPropagation(). Try using the capture phase: document.addEventListener('keypress', function......., **true**)

Comment: Could be a few things. Would've been helpful if you provided a link to the site. (1) the events are coming from within an ifram, (2) The site is built on react and handles events differently than non-react site, (3) An issue with word vs main context (i.e. content script vs on-page injected script)